# Jmeter please help me understand the logic

Tags: jmeter

I have a Selenium script that is taking username and password from a csv file and looping through all the rows to login and logout.  I am running this script from JMeter and I am able to see that Jmeter is doing its thing.  However, here is what I am not able to understand.

If my CSV file looks like this-

```
username1, pass1
username2, pass2
username3, pass3
```

when JMeter meter runs this script with 2 users, it does this-

```
username1
username1
username2
username2
username3
username3
```

I was expecting it to be

```
username1
username2
username3
username1
username2
username3
```

This may be really simple but I am not able to understand why Jmeter is doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `CSV Data Set Config` settings

- `Recycle on EOF?` - should be TRUE if you need to read the file again
- `Sharing Mode` should be All threads if all the threads need to share the file.

Comment: The CSV file input is given in Selenium not in Jmeter, All Jmeter is doing is run the class/method from Junit request. I plan to put the load on it.

Comment: @arm, Can you post your test plan?

Comment: I have screenshot of the test plan

Comment: @arm: what vins said: if you have CSV per thread, you get 112233112233 order, since each thread will run independently through the file; if all threads share file, the order will be 123123123123.